# Unfiltered data on/off

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I am using composite charts to see the unfiltered data, but I want to hide sometimes the unfiltered data and make the 'y' axis elastic. Hiding the unfiltered data wasn't hard, just an event listener on chart, but I can't make possible the elasticity on 'y' axis, when the unfiltered data is hidden. Perhaps it's not even possible in a case like this. Any ideas?

```
      chart.select('.unfiltered_data').on('change', function() {
        if(!this.checked) {
          console.log("Stop showing unfiltered data!")
          chart.select('.sub._0')
            .attr('visibility', 'hidden')
          // chart.elasticY(true)
          chart.redraw()
        }
        else {
          console.log("Show unfiltered data!")
          chart.select('.sub._0')
            .attr('visibility', 'visible')
          // chart.elasticY(false)
          chart.redraw()
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is (almost) always a way to do it in dc.js, because dc.js is a leaky abstraction by design!

First I tried to change which child charts are included in each composite chart, but that wasn't the right approach because a composite chart's children can't be changed on a redraw, only on a render. And we want to animate when switching between showing the unfiltered and not showing.

So instead I thought we could

- use your `visibility` idea
- turn off elasticY when the unfiltered is hidden, and
- use the filtered child chart's domain instead

So I added a checkbox

```
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="unfiltered" name="unfiltered" checked>&nbsp;Show Unfiltered</label>
```

and a global variable

```
  var show_unfiltered = true;
```

The handler looks like this:

```
  function ydomain_from_child1(chart) {
      chart.y().domain([0, chart.children()[1].yAxisMax()]);
      chart.resizing(true);
  }
  d3.select('#unfiltered').on('change', function() {
      show_unfiltered = this.checked;
      charts.forEach(chart => {
          chart.select('.sub._0').attr('visibility', show_unfiltered ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
          chart.elasticY(show_unfiltered);
          if(!show_unfiltered) {
              ydomain_from_child1(chart);
              chart.children()[1].colors(d3.schemeCategory10);
              chart.on('preRedraw.hide-unfiltered', ydomain_from_child1);
          }
          else {
              chart.children()[1].colors('red');
              chart.on('preRedraw.hide-unfiltered', null);
          }
      })
      dc.redrawAll();
  });
```

Whenever the checkbox is toggled, we turn on or off `elasticY` based on the setting. When the unfiltered are *not* shown, we'll *simulate* `elasticY` with a [preRedraw handler](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#on__anchor) which determines the domain from the second (filtered) child chart.

Additionally, we turn on/off the red color scheme for the filtered chart based on the checkbox.

I have added this to the [compare unfiltered example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/compare-unfiltered.html).

I found I had to make one more change: the filtered chart was hidden when there were no filters. So I had to disable this hiding if the unfiltered was unchecked:

```
var any_filters = !show_unfiltered || charts.some(chart => chart.filters().length);
chart.select('.sub._1')
    .attr('visibility', any_filters ? 'visible' : 'hidden')
```

Comment: (updated with rest of logic needed to add toggling to the example)

Comment: Glamorous. I really like the idea, but it doesn't work properly ([check this out](https://i.imgur.com/wyEoOTI.png)). At least this is what I think. 'y' domain doesn't update regarding the values of new updated bars. It can be easily observed in my case with an oridinal chart (sorry for the quality, I used paint). It does the magic, but the value indicated on the y axis is not the one associated to the bar, am I right? About the colors, I don't like seeing 3 different colors and I use only the base one and the 'deselected class' color.

Comment: Ah I see - the chart area updates but not the y axis, not good! Thanks for pointing that out. I’ll try to take a look this afternoon. I agree about the colors and will probably do the same thing - what you are doing is standard.

Comment: Okay, apparently you need to tell the coordinate grid charts they are resizing if you want the axes to adjust and elasticY is off. See added line above; I've also fixed the example and adopted the two-color scheme (simpler code too!)

Comment: Great, thanks for your help. About the colors, that's definitely the best option.

Comment: Update: There's something wrong with your example ([as you can see here](https://i.imgur.com/Ll44RZR.png)). I reseted all without the checkbox selected (that's not happening in my case).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Indeed I hadn't tested the Reset All button, which broke things by using `renderAll` instead of `redrawAll`. I fixed the example by handling the render cases, and for good measure I switched to `redrawAll` there, since it looks better.